# Bayer Image to H264

Tags: image, image-processing, video

I am working on 5MP sensor data to video display. My pipeline is as mentioned below.

Bayer data -> performed demosac -> Performed Dewraping -> some image processing like Brightness and contast correction etc -> converting to yuv420 for streaming-> displaying vedio at 15 fps.

I have not tested the above created pipeline as i am working on brightness and correction part.

problem area:- Do i have to create Panorama or image stitching with respect to next coming frame for perfect video to display , will there be difference in video sequence if i go with above created pipeline??

some where i was reading pitch roll, yaw HFOV radial correction has to be done. if this is so can you please post some link or method for lens spherical aberration and Chromatic aberration correction?
how should i start as i am doing de-wrapping which is perfectly working and removing if any lens distortion is there.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: your question is a bit broad. What are you trying to achieve? Why would you need to stitch a panorama for a perfect video to be displayed?

Comment: i am doing simple dewraping for correcting lens distortion of fish eye lens.
the problem evolve, if the camera is rotated to take video from different sequence then will it effect any issue?
there is no roll or pitch correction i am doing..